# How do I know the user's highest permission? Discord.js

Tags: discord.js

Hello I would like to know if the bot can register the user's highest permission? It would help a lot to know if it is possible to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can view the highest role of any member with [`GuildMemberRoleManager.highest`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=highest). If you're trying to compare positions, you can use the [`Role.position`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role?scrollTo=position) property.

```js
// example ban command
const target = message.mentions.members.first();

if (message.member.roles.highest.position <= target.roles.highest.permission)
  return message.channel.send('The target has a higher position than you.');
```

Another even easier way to do this is with [`Role.comparePositionTo()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role?scrollTo=comparePositionTo)

```js
if (target.roles.highest.comparePositionTo(message.member.roles.highest) < 1)
  return message.channel.send('The target has a higher position than you');
```

To view a member's permissions, you can use [`GuildMember.permissions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=permissions). If you only want to see if a user has certain permission, you can use [`GuildMember.hasPermissions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=hasPermission)

```js
if (!message.member.hasPermission('KICK_MEMBERS'))
  return message.channel.send('You do not have sufficient permissions.');
```

You can also use [`GuildMember.permissionsIn()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=permissionsIn) if you only want to take into account one channel with specific permission overwrites.

```js
const channel = message.client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === 'hammer-time');
if (!message.member.permissionsIn(channel).has('KICK_MEMBERS'))
  return message.channel.send('You do not have sufficient permissions.');
```

You can see a full list of permission flags (like `KICK_MEMBERS`, `BAN_MEMBERS`, etc.) [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Permissions?scrollTo=s-FLAGS)

Comment: It wasn't that, I'm doing a userinfo and I would like it to show what the highest permission of the mentioned user is

Comment: Unfortunately, permissions do not have an order to Discord API, so unless you have a certain role in mind, that's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the highest role of a member using [`GuildMemberroleManager#highest`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=highest):

```js
const highestRole = member.roles.highest
```

Discord.js can also calculate a member's permissions for you, using [`permissions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=permissions) and [`permissionsIn`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=permissionsIn):

```js
// The permissions for a member (all the permissions of their roles)
const permissions = member.permissions
// The permissions for a member, taking into account the permission overwrites
// for a channel
const permissionsInChannel = member.permissionsIn(channel)
```